# Error when create FrameBuffer: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I'm using libgdx, to create some program. I need used some operation in framebuffer. For this operation I create new framebuffer, after this operation I'm call in framebuffer dispose(). When I create framebuffer 10 time, I have crash program with error: frame buffer couldn't be constructed: incomplete dimensions.  I see at code libgdx and see that this is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS status of framebuffer. Why is it happened? What am I must to do to fixing this problem?

Code:

```
 if(maskBufferer != null){
     maskBufferer.dispose();
 }
 maskBufferer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, width, height, true);
 mask = createMaskImageMask(aspectRatioCrop, maskBufferer);
 ...

private Texture createMaskImageMask(boolean aspectRatioCrop, FrameBuffer maskBufferer) {
    maskBufferer.begin();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(COLOR_FOR_MASK, COLOR_FOR_MASK, COLOR_FOR_MASK, ALPHA_FOR_MASK);
    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    float[] coord = null;

    ...
    PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion( new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(texturePolygon)) ),
            coord);
    PolygonSprite poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
    PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
    polyBatch.begin();
    poly.draw(polyBatch);
    polyBatch.end();

    maskBufferer.end();
    return maskBufferer.getColorBufferTexture();
}
```

Comment: Post some code for analysis, please.

Comment: Without seeing any actual code, it is impossible to say. One interesting point is that OpenGL 3.0 Frame Buffer Objects do not have this restriction (that all attachments have the same dimensions). This implies to me that you are either using OpenGL ES or the EXT FBO extension (e.g. not OpenGL 3.0). Please include what version of OpenGL you are using, along with any code.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

To summarize, `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS` can occur in libgdx when too many `FrameBuffer` objects are created (without calling `.dispose()`), possibly to do with OpenGL running out of FBO or texture/renderbuffer handles.

If no handle is returned with `glGenFrameBuffers` then an FBO won't be bound when attaching targets or checking the status. Likewise an attempt to attach (from a failed call to `glGenTextures`) an invalid target will cause the FBO will be incomplete. Though it seems incorrect to report `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS` in either case.

One possibility may be the call to allocate memory for the target, such as `glTexImage2D` or `glRenderbufferStorage` has failed (out of memory). This leaves the dimensions of the target not equal to other targets already successfully attached to the FBO, and could then produce the error.

---

It's pretty standard to create a framebuffer once, attach your render targets and reuse each frame. By dispose do you mean [`glDeleteFrameBuffers`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glDeleteFramebuffers.xml)?

It looks like there should be `delete maskBufferer;` after and as well as `maskBufferer.dispose();`. *EDIT* if it were C++

Given this error happens after a number of frames it could be many things. Double check you aren't creating framebuffers or attachments each frame, not deleting them and running out of objects/handles.

It also looks like `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS` is [no longer used](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=4207.0) (see [the specs](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_object.txt)), something along the lines of the ability to have mixed dimensions now. Seems like it'd be worth checking that your attachments are all the same size though.

A quick way to narrow down which attachment is causing issues is to comment out half of them and see when the error occurs (or check the status after each attach).

Comment: In dispose() used gl.glDeleteFramebuffers(1, handle); But it did not help me

Answer (score 1):

I'm resolved problem. Dispose was helped. I was re-create the class every time, because of dispose was never call.

Comment: just out of interest, why was `maskBufferer != null` never passing? Or was `maskBufferer` not global or being initialized to `null` somewhere?

Comment: maskBufferer isn't global variable, it's variable of class. And all time I'm creating new object this class and I didn't have pointer to maskBufferer.